# Value of 1024 has one bit more in binary representation that value of 1

Tags: java, types, double, bit-representation

The output of following code:

```
System.out.println( Long.toBinaryString( Double.doubleToRawLongBits( 1 ) ) );
System.out.println( Long.toBinaryString( Double.doubleToRawLongBits( 1024 ) ) );
```

Is:

```
11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
100000010010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Why this code prints one bit more for value of 1024?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why this code prints one bit more for value of 1024?

This is because leading 000000's are dropped by Long.toBinaryString.  A `double` is always 64-bit, but it can have up to 63 leading zeros.

e.g.  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 is printed as 1

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(1));
```

The output is:

```
1
```

which indicates that `Long.toBinaryString()` discards the leading zeros.